# Is it possible to create a File with the android content uri path?

Tags: android, android-file

I am getting the path as follows from the cell phone gallery.

```
private fun fetchGalleryImages(context: Context, rowsPerLoad: Int): List<GalleryPicture> {
    val cursor = getGalleryCursor(context)

    if (cursor != null && !allLoaded) {
        val totalRows = cursor.count
        val galleryImageUrls = ArrayList<GalleryPicture>(totalRows)
        allLoaded = rowsToLoad == totalRows
        if (rowsToLoad < rowsPerLoad) {
            rowsToLoad = rowsPerLoad
        }

        for (i in startingRow until totalRows) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(i)
            val dataColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID) //get column index
        
            val imageURI = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                cursor.getLong(dataColumnIndex))

            val path = imageURI.toString()

            Log.d("ImagePath", "1) image path $path")

            galleryImageUrls.add(GalleryPicture(path)) //get Image path from column index
        }

        startingRow = rowsToLoad

        if (rowsPerLoad > totalRows || rowsToLoad >= totalRows)
            rowsToLoad = totalRows
        else {
            if (totalRows - rowsToLoad <= rowsPerLoad)
                rowsToLoad = totalRows
            else
                rowsToLoad += rowsPerLoad
        }

        cursor.close()
    
        return galleryImageUrls
    }

    return emptyList()
}

private fun getGalleryCursor(context: Context): Cursor? {
    val externalUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    val columns = arrayOf(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED)
    val orderBy = MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED //order data by modified
    return context.contentResolver
        .query(
            externalUri,
            columns,
            null,
            null,
            "$orderBy DESC"
        )//get all data in Cursor by sorting in DESC order
}
```

If you look at the first log above, the log to find the path of the image is shown, and the values ​​are as follows:

> content://media/external/images/media/18503

If I insert an image into `Glide` with the path specified above, the photo will be displayed normally.

> Glide.with(this).load(path).into(img)

The problem is that the `File` cannot be created with that path.

```
val file = File(path)
// always null...
```

The purpose is to create a `File` and export it to `S3` as `MultipartBody.Part`, how can I create a file?

Comment: [https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#direct-file-paths](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#direct-file-paths)

Comment: `val path = imageURI.toString()` That is no file path but a content scheme uri as you have seen. One cannot use a content scheme with the File class indeed. Moreover you can use the uri to upload the file. Google for multipartbodyinputstream.